# Generate a chunk name without hash

Tags: javascript, vite, rollupjs

For my specific condition I don't want to generate hash in file name for some specific files. I tried something like this, but its removing hash from .css files but not for the .js files.

```
  build: {
    target: 'es2020',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: fileURLToPath(new URL('./index.html', import.meta.url)),
        myapp: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/my-app.ts', import.meta.url))
      },
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          if (assetInfo.name?.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('myapp')) {
            return 'assets/[name][extname]';            
          }
          return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
        },
      },
```

Comment: I would debug the assetFileNames function to see if asseInfo includes the necessary fields. Are you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method entryFileNames as its the entry file.
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames